# Java Oracle Example Compiler Error

Tags: java, oracle, symbols

I'm trying to learn from the following example:
[CustomDialog.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/DialogDemoProject/src/components/CustomDialog.java)

However when I go to compile it I get the following error:

```
OracleExample.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
private DialogDemo dd;
        ^
symbol:   class DialogDemo
location: class CustomDialog
OracleExample.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
public CustomDialog(Frame aFrame, String aWord, DialogDemo parent) {
                                                ^
symbol:   class DialogDemo
location: class CustomDialog
2 errors
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use the DialogDemo.java code as well. Look at where you got the code from, and you should find the other class's code as well.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels How about an answer?

Comment: The tag `compiler` should be applied to questions concerning the programming of compilers or for questions about the detailed inner workings of compilers. Don't use `compiler` for questions about options and settings for a particular compiler, use the name of the compiler you are interested in instead.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the class that you're trying to use is not on the compiler's class path and is not imported (if need be).

Look here for a link to the needed class: [DialogDemo.java class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#DialogDemo)

Consider downloading the entire project.